# Specifying a format with scanf

Tags: c

Users need to enter a date in the format d-m-y specifically

Currently my code reads:

```
int date_read(int *d, int *m, int *y){
 
   scanf("%d%d%d', d, m, y)

return 1;
}
```

So I can accept the integers but I don't know how to verify that between those integers exists a hyphen. I cannot adjust the parameters input by the function.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You can put almost any character you want in the format string, and it should be matched verbatim. For example `"%d-%d-%d"`

Comment: Something like `if (scanf("%d -%d -%d", d, m, y) != 3) { /* Handle error */ }`?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1179/